# Datacontext of usercontrol is null

Tags: wpf, user-controls, observablecollection, datacontext

I have a viewmodel with an observablecollection member.

I created a usercontrol that binds with this collection and for *every* item in the collection I end up in the user controls constructor. In this constructor the datacontext is null, why is that?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMyCustomType}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <uc:Tile DataContext="{Binding Path=.}"></uc:Tile>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

**Edit:**
There are no BindingExpression errors in the debug output.

**Edit:**
Solved by Matthias, the datacontext is not available at *this time*. It will be available when the control is loaded or when the datacontext changes. Thumbs up!

Regards,

Michel

Comment: I guess I can even delete _binding path=._ since the control will use the default datacontext, i.e. the current item in the collection.

Comment: Your xaml looks fine. I could image the DataContext isn't set when the constructor is executed. Try to attach to the UserControl.Loaded event and use the DataContext there.

Comment: Even better: Use the DataContextChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the DataContext attribute and binding expression. Your user control will take on whatever item (inside the collection that the ItemsControl is bound to) is being bound to the current item's template.

Then in the loaded event of your control you should be able to access its DataContext:

```
var dataContext = this.DataContext as YourCustomType;
```